# Test view keeps dissapearing in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have visual studio 2008 TS both on my laptop as on my desktops(work & home).
For some reason the one on my laptop keeps removing the test view window from my window lay-out.
I can put it back by going Test=>windows=>test view, but as soon as my test run ends, the window is gona again. Quite anoying since I can't see the test results that way.

any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing "Reset" to your views (i.e. all the windows, placement and which are open), and re-arrange them all over again. It worked for me when my "Pending Changed" window kept re-duplicating and/or disappearing.